# Unity Build for Embedded Processors

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi, oculus

I am working on Unity project, and i want to connect it to raspberry pi board So as to connect with Oculus Rift, raspberry is ARM based processor. I build for Linux and try to run over raspberry Linux OS, but i fail. I think that's because unity builds only for Linux x64, x86. So, is there any way, i mean it. Anyway to make unity build works for Embedded Processors ??
Any help, discussion, or advice will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: You can still try the OpenGL path to making Oculus applications, that one should work on Raspberry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity's Standalone Linux builds only supports x86 and x64 CPUs, and does not support ARM, so there's no way to launch them on Raspberry Pi board. Even if it did support, there would be no guarantee that Linux running on Raspberry Pi would have all the necessary libraries to run your builds.